# How to control number of html elements through php?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a **HTML code** as shown below in which I want to control li tags through **php code**.

**HTML Code:**

```
<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>

<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>

<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>

<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>
```

**php code:**

```
<input type="text" name="no_articles_EN" style="width: 77.69px;height: 22px;" value="<?php if($data->{"no_articles_EN"}<>''){echo $data->{"no_articles_EN"};} ?>">   // Line#A

<input type="text" name="no_articles_FR" style="width: 77.69px;height: 22px;" value="<?php if($data->{"no_articles_FR"}<>''){echo $data->{"no_articles_FR"};} ?>">   // Line#B
```

At **Line#A** on php code above, let say if the value entered is **3(no_articles_EN)**, then li tags should be 3 as shown below:

**HTML Code:**

```
<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>

<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>

<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>
```

And if the value entered **2(no_articles_EN)** then li tags should be 2 as shown below:

**HTML Code:**

```
<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>

<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the HTML code above so if **no_articles_EN** is 3/4/5 then li tags should be vice versa. I came with the following logic but I think I need to more in it.

```
<?php
if($data->{"no_articles_EN"})   // Let say when no_articles_EN is 3 then li tags should be 3.  
{
?>
<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>
<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>
<li class="vidlist-main__item cf">
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the number of items dynamically when the value of the `input` changes? Or just when the page is loaded?

Comment: Not enough info here - waht is `$data` and how is it populated? Are your `input` tags part of a `form`? Do you want the user to have to submit the form before the update happens, or happen instantly (javascript)? Basically the solution is going to be some kind of `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

If `$data->no_articles_EN` is an integer equal to the number of items you want. Which is what  it appears to be you can use a simple `for` loop.

> if the value entered is 3(no_articles_EN), then li tags should be 3
>
> if the value entered 2(no_articles_EN) then li tags should be 2 as shown below:

I prefer the `ALT` PHP syntax when working with mixed content (PHP/HTML) it's just cleaner.  But if you prefer the `{...}` by all means use that.  The alt syntax uses a `:` and `end{command};` instead of the `{}`.  It's just easier to move the code around like this, easier to find the end tags etc.

```
<?php if($data->no_articles_EN): ?>  // Let say when no_articles_EN is 3 then li 
    <?php for($i=0; $i<$data->no_articles_EN; ++$i): ?>
        <li class="vidlist-main__item cf"></li>
    <?php endFor; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

You shouldn't use the variable property syntax `$data->{"no_articles_EN"}` unless you really need it, as it reduces readability and adds complexity when it's not needed.  That is mainly for things like this `$data->{"no_articles_".$language}` where you could have part of the property name as a variable.

Cheers!